# Add multiple exclusion filters to OpenCover

Tags: code-coverage, instrumentation, opencover

I know how I can add 1 exclusion filter but, what if I want to exclude multiple projects at one? Do I repeat the "-" statement? or is it comma separated? Particularly, I'm trying to exclude Tests and Installer from the coverage calculation:

```
<property name="coverage.report.filter" value="+[${product}*]* -[${product}*Installer.Designer*]* -[${product}*Tests]* " />
```

Sorry, newbie to OpenCover :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you type `OpenCover.Console.exe` on the command line I think you will see that it is accepts space separated filters. This is also detailed on the supplied documentation that should be installed with OpenCover - assuming you are using the download from GitHub.

The information is also available on the [WIKI](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/wiki/Usage)

Comment: I am doing exactly that but the report continues to show coverage for the Installer file, which I'm trying to exclude. This is how the filter looks like now:

value="+[${product}*]* -[*ProjectInstaller*]* -[*Installer*]*"

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "File" what do you mean by "File" - that parts of a filter are \[Module-Filter\]NameSpaceClass-Filter 
NOTE: depending on your VS settings the Module name and the File name (assembly) produced are the same but this is not necessarily the case.